# In Flex, how do I adjust the font size to align a label to an icon?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm building a small Flex UI component that displays a colored square next to a label of text. I want to be able to specify a size for the square and internally adjust the label's properties such that the line height matches the square and the text is vertically centered with respect to the square.

At the moment, I'm using `mx.controls.Label` for the text. Setting the `fontSize` style to the square's size does not work, the label then becomes too big. After tracing a couple of values in the debugger, I found that

- the line height of the internal text field (sum of the `ascent` and `descent` properties of the `TextFieldMetrics` object obtained through `getTextFieldMetircs()`) seems to end up about 120% of what I specify a s font size.
- there's a default "leading" of 2 pixels that I can not change directly at the `Label` level, this adds to the overall height of the internal text field (`getTextFieldMetrics().height`)
- the height of the `Label` component then is an additional 5 pixels larger than that, I don't know where those come from.

My current solution is to set the font size to `Math.round((iconSize - 2) / 1.2)` but while this works out OK-ish, it seems unsatisfactory. Is there a more reliable and more straightforward approach to this?

Comment: can you not just scale your label to fit the square rather than trying trying to work out the font size?

Comment: @Gregor - I have not tried that. When you say scaling, do you mean `setActualSize` or setting the scale factors that I think I remember from somewhere in the `UIComponent` or `DisplayObject` API? (Also, your comment should probably be posted as an answer, no?)

Comment: I mean setting scaleX and scaleY (You might need to embed the font for it to work) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#scaleX and I'll tell you what. If it works, I'll add it as an answer ;)

Comment: Good luck with that. From my experience sdk 3 is a mess when it comes to text measurement. Add to that the fact that the Label control has some hard-coded paddings, and you've got a recipe for pain. Haven't tried sdk 4, maybe they do things better there...

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have experimented a little with using a `UITextField` instead of a `Label` and that lead me to an interesting observation: Both components seem to do some internal scaling and resizing based on the font size, so that the rendered text will always have some padding around it. The numbers returned from `getTextLineMetrics()` are different for the same font size when using either component.

The `UITextField` renders the text such that the total pixel height of the component fits the number specified as `fontSize`, which in turn makes the actual text slightly smaller (about 2-4 pixels). Also, it seems to ignore when you set `leading` to zero.

The `Label` fits the resulting line height to what was specified as `fontSize`, making the component larger than that (by approximately 5 pixels).

While this is certainly confusing to me, I'm satisfied with using the `Label` component and positioning it such that the excess whitespace on top and bottom is clipped by the parent component and doesn't matter anymore. The text then has the right size. I'm centering vertically, which is easy, but it would also work to use the numbers from `getTextLineMetrics()` for more sophisticated positioning.